# RPM command hangs

Tags: linux, installation, rpm, glibc

On Cent OS 5, `rpm` command hung on my Linux machine.

```
[root@manage glib]# rpm -i libgcc-4.1.1-52.el5.i386.rpm

[root@manage glib]# ps -efww | grep libgcc
root      2020 32168  0 13:50 pts/0    00:00:00 grep libgcc
root     14254  2974  0 13:09 pts/1    00:00:00 rpm -i libgcc-4.1.1-52.el5.i386.rpm
```

Below is the `strace`:

```
[root@manage glib]# strace -p 14254
Process 14254 attached - interrupt to quit
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {0, 643179}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {1, 0})     = 0 (Timeout)
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {1, 0})     = 0 (Timeout)
read(4, "\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0a\25\6\0\7\0\0\0\0\20\0\0\0\10\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 256) = 256
close(4)                                = 0
open("/var/lib/rpm/Packages", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 4
fcntl(4, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
fstat64(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=5582848, ...}) = 0
brk(0x821e000)                          = 0x821e000
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {0, 1000})  = 0 (Timeout)
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {0, 2000})  = 0 (Timeout)
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {0, 4000})  = 0 (Timeout)
```

How do I fix `rpm` so it does not hang?

Comment: have you some nfs mounted in your system?

Comment: Maybe some pre/post install script hung? Try ``pstree -p `pidof -s rpm` ``

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Stop the install command and rebuild your rpm database.

You should be able to:

```
rm /var/lib/rpm/__db*
```

Then:

```
rpm --rebuilddb
```

Then attempt your installation again.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with nfs mount. 
rpm erase was hanging. 
I couldn't cancel (Ctrl-C) the rpm process.
There was no reason why rpm should have been accessing this mount point.

`df` command was also hanging. 
Compare `mount` and `df` output. 
The mount that df got stuck on was a problem. Two mounts were a problem for me.

`umount /badmount` didn't work "umount.nfs: /badmount: device is busy".
`umount --force -vvv /badmounts` got rid of the bad mount (remote machine was down). Then `kill <my rpm process>`. THen `rm /var/lib/rpm/__db* && rpm --rebuilddb`. From then on rpm working again.

---

`rpm -vvv` was useful and led me to think that mounts were a problem.
It was hanging after printing "mounted filesystems:"

```
$ rpm -e --noscripts -vvv PACKAGE
D: loading keyring from pubkeys in /var/lib/rpm/pubkeys/*.key
D: couldn't find any keys in /var/lib/rpm/pubkeys/*.key
D: loading keyring from rpmdb
D: opening  db environment /var/lib/rpm/Packages cdb:mpool:joinenv
D: opening  db index       /var/lib/rpm/Packages rdonly mode=0x0
D: locked   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Packages
D: opening  db index       /var/lib/rpm/Name rdonly mode=0x0
D:  read h#    1489 Header sanity check: OK
D: added key gpg-pubkey-57bbccba-4a6f97af to keyring
D: Using legacy gpg-pubkey(s) from rpmdb
D:  read h#     912 Header SHA1 digest: OK (9fda42f8af7a801b81d14291987d1052d2c17c53)
D: ========== --- OMN-Traffic-Control-vx.xx.xx-1.FC9 i686/linux 0x0
D: opening  db index       /var/lib/rpm/Requirename rdonly mode=0x0
D: ========== recording tsort relations
D: ========== tsorting packages (order, #predecessors, #succesors, tree, depth, breadth)
D:     0    0    0    0    1    0   -OMN-Traffic-Control-vx.xx.xx-1.FC9.i686
D: erasing packages
D: closed   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Requirename
D: closed   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Name
D: closed   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Packages
D: closed   db environment /var/lib/rpm/Packages
D: opening  db environment /var/lib/rpm/Packages cdb:mpool:joinenv
D: opening  db index       /var/lib/rpm/Packages create mode=0x42
D: mounted filesystems:
D:     i        dev    bsize       bavail       iavail mount point
```

---

An ltrace was vaguely interesting but didn't give any clue to problem.

```
$ ltrace rpm -e PACKAGE
__libc_start_main(0x8049680, 3, 0xffab6264, 0x804ae90, 0x804ae80 <unfinished ...>
mtrace()                                                                                                      = <void>
strrchr("rpm", '/')                                                                                           = NULL
setlocale(6, "")                                                                                              = "en_US.UTF-8"
bindtextdomain("rpm", "/usr/share/locale")                                                                    = "/usr/share/locale"
textdomain("rpm")                                                                                             = "rpm"
rpmlogSetMask(63, 0x99a390, 0xf63d4e2e, 0xb3ff08, 28)                                                         = 63
poptGetContext(0x804af4c, 3, 0xffab6264, 0x804ce40, 0)                                                        = 0x98528d8
rpmConfigDir(0x804af4c, 3, 0xffab6264, 0x804ce40, 0)                                                          = 0xce2432
rpmGenPath(0xce2432, 0x804af75, 0, 0x804ce40, 0)                                                              = 0x9852b40
poptReadConfigFile(0x98528d8, 0x9852b40, 0, 0x804ce40, 0)                                                     = 0
free(0x9852b40)                                                                                               = <void>
poptReadDefaultConfig(0x98528d8, 1, 0, 0x804ce40, 0)                                                          = 0
rpmConfigDir(0x98528d8, 1, 0, 0x804ce40, 0)                                                                   = 0xce2432
poptSetExecPath(0x98528d8, 0xce2432, 1, 0x804ce40, 0)                                                         = 1
poptGetNextOpt(0x98528d8, 0xce2432, 1, 0x804ce40, 0)                                                          = -1
rpmcliConfigured(0x98528d8, 0xce2432, 1, 0x804ce40, 0)                                                        = 0
urlIsURL(0xd487af, 0xce2432, 1, 0x804ce40, 0)                                                                 = 0
rpmLookupSignatureType(1, 0xce2432, 1, 0x804ce40, 0)                                                          = 0
rpmtsCreate(1, 0xce2432, 1, 0x804ce40, 0)                                                                     = 0x98729c8
rpmtsSetRootDir(0x98729c8, 0xd487af, 1, 0x804ce40, 0)                                                         = 0
poptPeekArg(0x98528d8, 0xd487af, 1, 0x804ce40, 0)                                                             = 0xffab7622
poptGetArgs(0x98528d8, 0xd487af, 1, 0x804ce40, 0)                                                             = 0x9852a70
rpmErase(0x98729c8, 0xd5c440, 0x9852a70, 0x804ce40, 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pstree -p `pidof -s rpm`
```

worked for me. 
I was running ps commands trying to grep for the process but I didn't find them all.

```
pstree -p `pidof -s rpm`
```

worked but I had to run it about 4 - 5 times to find and get rid all of the old pids.

And I had to use kill -9 to make them go away. Normal kill and killall wouldn't work.